# Adding objects to binary search tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm completely new to BST and how they work if this is completely wrong it would be appreciated if I could get a link to a reference site or something. right now I'm writing a program to add values from an `ArrayList` of `String`s to a BST and I come up with errors such as The method `compareTo(Node)` is undefined for the type `ArrayList<String>`. I thought by having `extends Comparable` it would account for comparing `ArrayList` values but I'm not using `E`. Also I had to add a cast to s to set it as the root but I feel like there is an easier way. I don't know if I can add `ArrayList` values the way I'm doing it, this is just how it looks in the book I'm using for reference. This is my code, any help would be appreciated, I already tried looking up things in the Java API and that didn't help:

```
public class BinarySearchTree<E extends Comparable<? super E>>

{

    public void add(ArrayList<String> s, Node n) {


            if (n == null)
                 n = (Node) s;
            else if (s.compareTo(n) < 0)
                 add(s, n.leftChild);
            else
                 add(s, n.rightChild);


    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly does "add()" do? it seems like you're trying to add ArrayLists into a BST, rather than add values FROM and ArrayList into the BST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this reference would be helpful to you: [Binary Search Trees - Stanford Library](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/110/BinaryTrees.html)

Comment: This is one of the best references I have seen.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the Node class should extend Comparable and override the compareTo method in it. ArrayList class doesn't extend Comparable and hence the following will not work

s.compareTo(n) < 0

s being an ArrayList reference. Also, you are trying to compare an ArrayList reference with a Node reference which is totally incorrect. You need to compare two Node values.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to add the entire ArrayList as a single node of your BST. My guess is that you are supposed to construct a BST from the *elements* of the ArrayList. For that, I would suggest defining two functions:

```
public Node add(ArrayList<String> s, Node root) {
    for (String elt : s) {
        root = add(elt, root);
    }
}

public Node add(String elt, Node root) {
    if (root == null) {
        root = // new Node with data set to elt
    } else if (elt.compareTo(n.data()) < 0) {
        root.left = add(elt, root.left);
    } else if (elt.compareTo(n.data()) > 0) {
        root.right = add(elt, root.right);
    } else {
        // duplicate element being inserted -- error?
    }
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Yes I do have to add each element from the ArrayList to a BST. Thank you for the help! One question though, what do you mean by n.data(). Should I set n to each value in the ArrayList?